# Reduce image quality when resizing with bitmap

Tags: bitmap, image-resizing

I Use this code to resize image:

```
int w=Integer.parseInt(edw.getText().toString());
        int h=Integer.parseInt(edh.getText().toString());
        resized = Bitmap. createScaledBitmap ( myBitmap,w, h , true ) ;
        //
        
        
        
        Bitmap bitmap=resized;
        
            out = new FileOutputStream(getFilename());
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
```

The code works correctly, but when I compare the output image of this code with the output image of other programs (in terms of size, both images are the same size), but the output of this code is more pixelated.And it is less clear.

Comment: CompressFormat is same ?

Comment: I don't know this exactly because I don't know which CompressFormat used in other app. Is there any CompressFormat with better quality? If there is, please tell me